# C# Debug and Trace Logs Not Being Captured

Tags: c#, logging, .net-6.0

I've got a simple .NET6 Console app to test logging configurations. I'm not using appsettings.json - just building the logger as shown below.

I set the filter to be "Trace", but I only get Information, Error, and Critical. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help is appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

ILogger? logger;

ConfigureServices();

logger?.LogInformation("Information");
logger?.LogDebug("Debug");
logger?.LogTrace("Trace");
logger?.LogError("Error");
logger?.LogCritical("Critical");

await Task.Delay(1000);

void ConfigureServices()
{
    string sourceName = "LoggerTest";

    var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .ClearProviders()
            .AddFilter(sourceName, LogLevel.Trace)
            .AddConsole();
    });

    logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
    logger.BeginScope(sourceName);
}
```

My Output:

```
info: Program[0]
      Information
fail: Program[0]
      Error
crit: Program[0]
      Critical
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out . . . there's a "SetMinimumLevel()" function:

```
    var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder
            .ClearProviders()
            .AddFilter(sourceName, LogLevel.Trace)
            .AddConsole()
            .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
    });
```